# Synonyms for light table

Tags: film, slides, light-box

I have a relatively stupid question this time, probably caused by my poor English. I'm looking to buy a [light table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_table) (an illuminated device to view transparencies/slides on), alternatively called [light panel](http://www.scandig.com/light-panels/index.html), but whenever I search these terms from Ebay, I get a lot of light tables (light like low weight), table lights (light like lamp). I've also tried terms "light panel" and "light box", which mostly return some kind of illuminated advertisements. I also tried some brands known to produce them, like Kaiser and Reflecta, but no luck. I somehow refuse to accept nobody actually sells these things.

So how do you guys call it :)? If anybody knows the term in German, I'd be interested too, because I get most of my stuff from UK an DE Ebay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called "light boxes", like for example [this one from Hama](http://www.hama.co.uk/portal/articleId*452/action*2563;jsessionid=FCEA38699008D89DA63C55E52006615E.tomcat_uk_lin28). In german it's "leuchtpult": [same page on the german site](http://www.hama.de/portal/articleId*452/action*2563;jsessionid=FCEA38699008D89DA63C55E52006615E.tomcat_uk_lin28)

Answer (score 2):

Something to view film transparencies on? If I understand what your asking, I know them as Light Boxes, or possibly Light Tables. I think light box is a pretty well known term for it, given that the term "light box" has also been used for years to refer to the digital variety on the web...those javascript API's that dim a web site and pop up a photo in a centered DIV, making them easier to view.

I can't help you much with the German part much. I'm a dumb english-only speaker. ;P

Comment: For transparencies/slides, yes. Thanks, looks like I just need to browse through a couple of thousand tables and lamps :)

Answer (score 1):

Light boxes are also a term used for traditional animation, so you may be seeing some of these come up as well. They're basically the same thing as a light table, but it generally has an insert at the top and bottom for a peg bar. Here is one by a company that makes those same types of lightboxes, but is better suited for what you're looking for (and it's portable): http://cgi.ebay.de/LED-Leuchttisch-Lightpad-A920-Lighttracer-Tracer-/310231751225?pt=Modellbauwerkzeuge&hash=item483b40da39

Answer (score 1):

Lightbox and "transparency viewer" seem to work the best as terms on Ebay.

Write lightbox as a single word for best results (not "light box").

Unfortunately, there is one word to describe two different photographic things, so it's not a perfect search.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe nobody has said "Overhead Projector" that's the only name I've ever heard anyone use to refer to that device.

Comment: An overhead projector is used when you want to project the image of a transparency onto a screen. Overhead projectors involve very bright lights, and some sort of focusing system (usually a lens and a mirror.) The device Karel is asking about is essentially a box with a light and a frosted glass panel, on which you can put slides for personal viewing.

Comment: Yes, Evan is right. Light box is where you do the sorting and editing before projecting.